# jQuery: remove Last <td> of the first 2 lines

Tags: jquery

How can I remove the last `td` from the first 2 lines using jquery? I have this: 
`$('#mainmenu  tr td:last-child').remove();` ,

this remove in all lines so how can I remove for the first **2 lines**?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XbGSV/62/

```js
$('#mainmenu  tr td:last-child').remove();
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" id="mainmenu">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 1
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 2
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 3
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 11
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 22
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 33
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 11
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 22
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 33
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery [`:lt()`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) pseudo-class selector to get elements less than the index provided.

```
$('#mainmenu  tr:lt(2) td:last-child').remove();
```

```js
$('#mainmenu  tr:lt(2) td:last-child').remove();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" id="mainmenu">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 1
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 2
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 3
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 11
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 22
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 33
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 11
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 22
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 33
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

---

Or use [`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) pseudo-class selector with custom `-n + 2` equation, where value of `n` would be `0, 1, 2,...` so the result would be `2, 1, 0, -1...` so the first 2 get selected remaining will ignored (`0, -1,...` are not valid element index since which is 1 - indexed).

```
$('#mainmenu  tr:nth-child(-n+2) td:last-child').remove();
// or
$('#mainmenu  tr:not(:nth-child(n+3)) td:last-child').remove();
```

```js
$('#mainmenu  tr:nth-child(-n+2) td:last-child').remove();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" id="mainmenu">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 1
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 2
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 3
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 11
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 22
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 33
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 11
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 22
                </td>
                <td valign="top" class="menu_sub">
                    something 33
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: thank you, I don't know why, but in my local code just :nth-child() worked, :), but thank you very much for this.

Comment: @Raduken :  there is slight difference... if there is multiple tables then `:lt` works on the entire collection of `tr`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`:lt`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector to select the first n elements

```
#mainmenu  tr:lt(2) td:last-child
```

Answer (score 0):

use the :lt selector to select the first n elements

```
#example  tr:lt(2) td:last-child

$('#example  tr:lt(2) td:last-child').remove();
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XbGSV/63/